# Show popup when mouse leave in another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have one whole html page which has script to show the pop up when mouse leave in browser window. When user want to close the tab on browser the popup will be show. I already create that page and it works properly in **example.com**. In this case I want to call that page in another site called **exampletwo.com**, so when user want to close the **exampletwo.com** the popup from my page in **example.com** will be triggered and show in **exampletwo.com**. Which I want is some script or iframe to show that popup page from my site **example.com** to **exampletwo.com**. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseY = 0;
        var popupCounter = 0;

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
            mouseX = e.clientX;
            mouseY = e.clientY;
            //document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = "<br />X: " + e.clientX + "px<br />Y: " + e.clientY + "px";
        });

        $(document).mouseleave(function () {
            if (mouseY < 100) {
                if (popupCounter < 1) {
                    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                }
                popupCounter ++;
            }
        });

        //var span = document.getElementById("close");


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $( "#close" ).click(function() {
          var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
                    modal.style.display = "none";
        });

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
          display: none; /* Hidden by default */
          position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
          z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%; /* Full width */
          height: 100%; /* Full height */
          overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
          background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content/Box */
        .modal-content {
          background-color: #fefefe;
          margin-right: 0%; /* 15% from the top and centered */
          padding: 0px;
          border: 1px solid #888;
          width: 30%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        #close {
          color: #aaa;
          float: right;
          font-size: 28px;
          font-weight: bold;
        }

        #close:hover,
        #close:focus {
          color: black;
          text-decoration: none;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="close">&times;</div>
        <a href="<?=$image->link?>" target="_blank">
            <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/<?=$image->images?>" style="width: 100%;">
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is some example which I want, this script works properly to show the popup in another site but I don't understand how it works. I copied from some company which provide remarketing.:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        try{ var shopUrlCYB = 'yoursite.com'
            !function(){var t=function(t){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript",e.async=!0,e.src=t;var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n)},e=Math.floor(5e4*Math.random());t("//d2rp1k1dldbai6.cloudfront.net/cybba_latest.min.js"),t("https://files1.cybba.solutions/"+shopUrlCYB+"/loader.min.js?v="+e),window._vteq=window._vteq||[],setTimeout(function(){window._vtsdk||t("https://storage.googleapis.com/cybcdn/"+shopUrlCYB+"/loader.js?v="+e)},1100),setTimeout(function(){"nestedVarDefined"in window&&!nestedVarDefined("_vtsdk.state.eventQueue")&&"_vtsdk"in window&&_vtsdk.init()},3e3)}();
        }catch(e){}
    </script>
```

Comment: why not simply copy the script from site1 to site2?

Comment: @madalinivascu I don't have access to site2. The developer of site2 couldn't copy the whole html page but they need some script or iframe to show the popup from my site.

Comment: send them the html script directly if they can't copy it from your site,why does he need your site resources?

Comment: @madalinivascu They don't want to copy whole html page from my site. Please take a look again in sample script I already added on my questions above.

Comment: from what i can see from the script the second site is accessing the first site resources, some js files, why not sent the developer form site2 the js files to host them on their system ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot observe site 2 events from site 1. Using an iframe would not fix the problem, since you cannot close an iframe as a normal window. Javascript is a browser language with restrictions, communications between different windows are not allowed, for the same reason why cookies from different domains are not allowed.

Comment: Please take a look again on some script which already working but I don't understand how that script works in my questions above.